# Do svg text elements have content attributes?

Tags: xml, svg

Do svg text elements have content attributes?

I believe this can be achieved with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("test").textContent("Some meaningful verbage");
```

Can this be achieved without javascript? Ex.gr.:

```
<text id='test' content="Some meaningful verbage"></text>
```

Comment: No, the text goes between the end of the start tag and the start of the end tag. Can what be achieved without javascript? What you've written can be achieved with a text editor, although it won't display anything.

Comment: I edited to clarify.

Comment: Doesn't seem much clearer to me.

Comment: What more specifically is unclear? I'm wondering about setting the text of a <text> element through an attribute . . .

Comment: I think the answer is no then, the text element displays text content not an attribute. You could convert one to the other with javascript or XSLT though.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot put the text of a svg text element in an attribute you can append a text element (with text) with javascript like this.

```js
function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v)
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) { return "-" + m.toLowerCase(); }), v[p]);
  return n
}

var svg = getNode("svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var text = getNode('text', {x:"15", y:"15", fill: "black"});
text.append("some meaningful text");
svg.appendChild(text);
```